# CKAN - file size appearing null in Postgres database

Tags: postgresql, ckan

I've installed CKAN on Ubuntu using the Postgres database. Some uploaded files are showing as having null size in the database (Resource table). However I can download the file from the URL and it is a couple of MB. Does anyone know why the size value is not showing?

Answer (score 0):

After loading a large amount of data, you should always run `VACUUM ANALYZE` to make sure that the system knows about the new data. VACUUM ANALYZE will update statistics and that is reflected in the system catalogs. Those statistics are also used for query optimizations so it is crucial that you do the VACUUM as soon as possible after loading the data.

Vacuuming takes place automatically but on a schedule, so unless you do a manual vacuum it takes a while before the new data is properly accounted for in the system catalogs.

Comment: Thanks Patrick. Unfortunately it still does not work after running this command. Only approx 4 files were uploaded from the web UI, and each of these files are less than 1MB.

Comment: Vacuum has nothing to do with the fact that the database does not contain the expected data.

Answer (score 0):

CKAN actually doesn't store the file size yet. The old filestore was incapable of doing this. From CKAN 2.2 and above, the new filestore is able to do this and we're tracking this in Issue [#1517](https://github.com/ckan/ckan/issues/1517). I'll probably fix it myself when I get a chance.